# Error while posting Check In on facebook using Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating the latest facebook iOS sdk in my application.I am getting near by facebook places but when I check in the particular place I am getting this error

```
error =         {
            code = 200;
            message = "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_checkins";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
```

Can someone help me how to get this extended "publish_checkins" permission :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the July 2013 Breaking Changes in fb

Publishing a Checkin object is deprecated in favor of creating an Open Graph story with a location attached. You can also create a Post with a location attached using the 'publish_steam' extended permission.

For detailed info read **Removing 'publish_checkins' permissions** in [July 2013 roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)

Comment: Hey mate, I know this flow and i am doing it exactly this way ... but the thing which I unable to understand is how to get this extended Permission "publish_checkins" with the new facebook iOS sdk.Can you help me with any sample code as there is no such method to get the extended permissions on FBSession?

Comment: did you go through the blog given in my answer. This definitely will help you a lot with sample code

Comment: Actually the method used in this blog are no longer available in new facebook iOS sdk 3.6 :(

Comment: So I do need to replace me/checkins with post/me in graph API with the same parameters. right?

Comment: Still no luck not the error is Unknown path components: /me. Both me/post or post/me not working :(

Comment: it is got deprecated recently only i.e. on 10th of July, 2013. That's why we are not getting the exact solution. I'm in research of it continuesly

Comment: Thanks for your time mate... Do tell me if you find any fix.I am kinda stuck here

Comment: This error occurs because of invalid fbRequest. You should try with /me/<namespace>:<action type>

Comment: what could be the name space and action type here?